# Leverage Twitter / Facebook credentials by pulling information from other app

Tags: android, facebook, twitter

I'm being asked if it's possible to have the ability to leverage facebook and twitter credentials by pulling account information from apps that are already installed and authenticated.

This means: an app is running and the user is logged in through FB or TW. Then, it launches my app. Could get those credentials and keep the user logged in on my app too?
I think this could be not so good to do it, but they are asking to me for an answer.

I did research and didn't find anything related, so I am thinking that it's not possible.

Could anyone confirm this or tell me how it could be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. Each application must be registered on the respective social network, to obtain a application key and application secret. You then have to request a authorisation token from the server of the social network. Since the token is based on the specific application key and secret, even if you would be able to leverage this authorisation token (say on a rooted device), it would be useless to you, because you´d also have to know the key and secret. Ands Facebook matches the app signature as a extra layer of security.

Plain and simple no :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to share data to Twitter or Facebook from your app, you should do this by using a share Intent. This way you push the data to whatever app (FB or Twitter, or others like email and messaging) while the user picks which app they choose to publish this data on. See more info at the developer blog here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/02/share-with-intents.html

And tutorial here:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent/

If you want to do specific things with the authenticated account, like retrieve the user's timeline or wall posts, I don't think you'd be able to borrow that authenticated token from another app. You will have to register your app with each social network, ask the user his/her credentials and obtain a token. Then you can grab data from these services.

Comment: Based on the below post, I couldn't be sharing the token between apps, so I am wondering that this is not possible.

Comment: Well, esilac has a point. My answer still stands, but both FB and  implement ways in their API to provide similar functionality to the native apps, like described by esilac. But you well never be able to use credentials of another application. And like you pointed out yourself, it's a good thing this isn't possible